# Не могу получить ссылку на страницу товара API Яндекс Маркет

Tags: python, яндекс-маркет

Никак не могу получить ссылку на страницу товара в Яндекс Маркет.
Получаю все нужные мне параметры, кроме ссылки на страницу.
Ссылка выглядит так:
https://market.yandex.ru/<product_name>/<product_id>
Но ссылку также можно получать путем создания url
https://market.yandex.ru/product/<product_id>
Однако product_id нигде не выдается

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Где вы пытаетесь это всё получить и каким образом?

Comment: @CrazyElf , я использую [официальное API Яндекс Маркет](https://yandex.ru/dev/market/partner-api/doc/ru/). 
В [этом](https://yandex.ru/dev/market/partner-api/doc/ru/reference/assortment/getCampaignOffers) эндпоинте я получаю все данные о товаре, кроме его id (которое нужно для формирования ссылки на страницу товара) или самого url-адреса страницы товара на маркетплейсе.

Comment: Аналогичная проблема. Удалось как-то решить вопрос?

Comment: Нет, проблему решить так и не удалось